# By clicking on box1 change value from box2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I need your help, I'm looking for a solution of:
There is a form with several checkboxes, but only 4 of them are important. Here the html code from this 4:

```
<input name="opt[pool]" id="opt_pool" type="checkbox" class="searchval" value="1" onclick="submit_search()">Pool
<input name="opt[ppool]" id="opt_ppool" type="checkbox" class="searchval" value="1" onclick="submit_search()">PPool

<input name="opt[internet]" id="opt_internet" type="checkbox" class="searchval" value="1" onclick="submit_search()">Internet
<input name="opt[internetw]" id="opt_internetw" type="checkbox" class="searchval" value="1" onclick="submit_search()">InternetW
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
function build_search(skip){
    var sparam = ''; 
    var fields = {};
    $('.searchval').each(function(index){          
        if($(this).attr('name')==skip) {}
        else if($(this).attr('type')=='checkbox'||$(this).attr('type')=='radio'){
            if($(this).prop("checked")){
                sparam+=$(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).attr('value')+"&";
                fields[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
            }
        }
        else if($(this).val()!=undefined&&$(this).val()!=''){
            sparam+=$(this).attr('name')+"="+$(this).val()+"&";
            fields[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    });
}
```

Now I would like to intervene - when clicked on pool, this checked with val=1 and ppool unchecked with val=0. And reverse when click on ppool htis checked with val=1 and pool unchecked with val=0.
This works with my code:

```
var boxesP = $('#opt_pool,#opt_ppool').click(function(){
    boxesP.not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $("#opt_pool").val( $("#opt_pool")[0].checked ? "0" : "1" );
    $("#opt_ppool").val( $("#opt_ppool")[0].checked ? "0" : "1" );
});
```

But the problem is when i click to other checkboxes, the checked pool with val=1, remains checked but the val=0.
Where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Use prop. $("#opt_pool").prop( 'checked', $("#opt_pool")[0].checked ? false : true );

Comment: Btw avoid ID's Use classes.

Comment: @user2330678 Or just `$("#opt_pool").prop( 'checked', !$("#opt_pool")[0].checked);`

Comment: Thanks for your time, but they not work likes i want. Y have change my code to var boxesP = $('#opt_pool,#opt_ppool').click(function(){
        boxesP.not(this).prop('checked', false);
        $("#opt_pool").prop( 'checked', !$("#opt_ppool")[0].checked);
        $("#opt_ppool").prop( 'checked', !$("#opt_pool")[0].checked);        
    });

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have an existing onClick function. Would something like this work for you?

```
<input name="opt[pool]" id="opt_pool" type="checkbox" class="searchval" value="0" onclick="submit_search(this)">Pool
<input name="opt[ppool]" id="opt_ppool" type="checkbox" class="searchval" value="0" onclick="submit_search(this)">PPool
submit_search = function(e){
        if($(e).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
            $('.searchval').attr('checked',null);
            $('.searchval').val(0);
            $(e).attr('checked','checked');
            $(e).val(1);
        }else{
            $(e).val(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, because there not unchecked ppool when i click pool

Comment: I would like to explain more exactly what I want to do: If click on pool, pool will be cheked. When I click on Pool again pool should be unchecked. Then y click ppool, and if pool is checked must be unchecked. And revers, if ppool ist checked and i click pool i want that the ppool will unchecked. I hope i not confuse with my bad english ;)

Comment: But also important is when one box is checked the val=1 and if unchecked change the val=0

Comment: Can anyone help me to give the correct hint? Thanks